# ng-else directive in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ng-if

how can we create `ngELSE` directive as same as `ngIF` directive?

below code for `ngIfDirective`. Shall we customize the code for `ngELSE`?

```
var ngIfDirective = ['$animate', function($animate) {
  return {
    multiElement: true,
    transclude: 'element',
    priority: 600,
    terminal: true,
    restrict: 'A',
    $$tlb: true,
    link: function($scope, $element, $attr, ctrl, $transclude) {
        var block, childScope, previousElements;
        $scope.$watch($attr.ngIf, function ngIfWatchAction(value) {

          if (value) {
            if (!childScope) {
              $transclude(function(clone, newScope) {
                childScope = newScope;
                clone[clone.length++] = document.createComment(' end ngIf: ' + $attr.ngIf + ' ');
                // Note: We only need the first/last node of the cloned nodes.
                // However, we need to keep the reference to the jqlite wrapper as it might be changed later
                // by a directive with templateUrl when its template arrives.
                block = {
                  clone: clone
                };
                $animate.enter(clone, $element.parent(), $element);
              });
            }
          } else {
            if (previousElements) {
              previousElements.remove();
              previousElements = null;
            }
            if (childScope) {
              childScope.$destroy();
              childScope = null;
            }
            if (block) {
              previousElements = getBlockNodes(block.clone);
              $animate.leave(previousElements).then(function() {
                previousElements = null;
              });
              block = null;
            }
          }
        });
    }
  };
}];
```

Comment: You directives are not there to define process using if and else and hence i believe there is no ngElse. Negation of ngif will act like ngElse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally we use like this

normal **if-else**

```
if(video == video.large){
    <!-- code to render a large video block-->
}
else{
    <!-- code to render the regular video block -->
}
```

AngularJS **[ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)**

```
<div ng-if="video == video.large">
    <!-- code to render a large video block-->
</div>
<div ng-if="video != video.large">
    <!-- code to render the regular video block -->
</div>
```

But if you are too specific that you want a directive like `ng-if`, `ng-else-if`, and `ng-else` then use **[ng-elif](https://github.com/zachsnow/ng-elif#ng-elif)**

**[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/XSPP3jZL8eehu9G750ME?p=preview)**

```
 <div ng-if="someCondition">
    ...
  </div>
  <p>
    Some random junk in the middle.
  </p>
  <div ng-else-if="someOther && condition">
    ...
  </div>
  <div ng-else-if="moreConditions">
    ...
  </div>
  <div ng-else>
    ...
  </div>
```

Comment: Is doubt about,  is first if condition is true, then the else condition will not execute or execute?

Comment: @RameshRajendran what condition you want to be tested under this

Answer (score 5):

En else statement wouldn't make much sense on its own.

You can mimick an `else` statement in 2 ways with vanilla AngularJS

### 1. Simply use the negated check in a second ng-if

```
<div ng-if='myConditionIsTrue'></div>
<div ng-if='!myConditionIsTrue'></div>
```

### 2. use the ngSwitch directive

```
<div ng-switch="myCondition">
    <div ng-switch-when="true"></div>
    <div ng-switch-default></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this, its the reverse of ng-if. Simply saying `!` (NOT) Value has the same effect as ng-else would. There are ng-else-if (called [ng-elif](https://github.com/zachsnow/ng-elif)) directives as well, if that's more what you're looking for.

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl as ctrl">
    <div ng-if="ctrl.isTrue">If</div>
    <div ng-if="!ctrl.isTrue">If</div>
</div>
```

Though there is literally no point to creating an ng-else directive when you can simply negate the checked value in ng-if, you can modify the ng-if directive like so to achieve the exact same thing

```
    $scope.$watch($attr.ngIf, function ngIfWatchAction(value) {

      if (!value) { // add the ! here instead and name this new directive ngElse
```

Comment: I know it dude, but i want ng-else, can we  create a new directives for ngELSE?

Answer (score 1):

In this it has explained how you could use the ng-else through ng-elif

Example:

```
<div ng-if="someTest" ng-then="theTestPassed">
  Some things that assume that "someTest" is true.
</div>
<div ng-else="theTestPassed">
  Some other things that assume that "someTest" is false.
</div>
```

http://zachsnow.com/#!/blog/2014/angularjs-ng-elif/

Also see this: http://plnkr.co/edit/XSPP3jZL8eehu9G750ME?p=preview

Comment: ng-else will call if my `if` condition is true?

Comment: @RameshRajendran `ng-else` in this example is really just a negated `ng-if`. So `ng-then` sets `theTestPassed` to `true` when `someTest` is `true`, and then `ng-else` essentially checks `!theTestPassed`.